# funny thing with Microsoft C# class library build which says it needs Main method to build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This code below doesn't get build but gives me error that it misses Main method. So funny and ridiculous.

```
class Program
{

    public abstract class ClassA
    {
        public virtual void A()
        {
        }
    }
    class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public void B()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Class library, really?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the build properties tab? My guess is that you haven't actually set it to be a class library - but a WinForms, console or WPF app.

Comment: @ken2k: Shamefully yes it is

Comment: @Habib: Of course not F5 but F6 :D

Comment: `funny and ridiculous` usually means user error in my experience

Comment: @Divine Sorry but no, it isn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you so much, I corrected it with your guidance. I am really sorry for silly things. Just learning :)

Comment: @ken2k: thank you it works now. Followed Jon Skeet and you.

Comment: Anyone wanna take bet that Divine is from java background?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: lol I am not from programming background :P Of course I am a Microsoft Fan :) And I am from Electronics and Communication background :( I am learning programming :) When I am learning, some questions I get myself logically, and sometime I do not really have a sufficient justification to accept few things. One such example is, a class having both private and public constructor let us create the object of it outside, contrary to Private constructor rubric which says, we can't create instance of class with private constructor except within the nested class.

Comment: If you have ALSO public constructor(s), you can create instance of a class outside of the class... If you have ONLY private constructor then the case is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you didn't set it to Class Library.
Check your project properties.

Comment: Thank you SLaks, helped me :)